# Controller shows only blue lines in storyboard in Xcode 9.0?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, xcode9

I have designed one controller in my storyboard. When I was designing it was fine & I was able to view all views. but today morning when I opened it shows only blue lines nothing else.Whereas other controller shows the views in the same storyboard.

When I click randomly on the controller on different then Xcode also getting crashed.

[image]

I have tried restarting the Xcode & my Mac also but this does not go. I also cleaned the drive data for Xcode.

Comment: Yes but it was working fine before

Comment: This is not a solution. I am telling you I have been custom classes for a long time but I never has such issue with custom classes. my issue is related to the storyboard.Kindly guide me on that

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode -> Go to Editor -> Canvas

1. uncheck Show Bounds Rectangles
2. uncheck Show Layouts Rectangles

Answer (score 0):

Took help from online, and found a solution for you, tell me if it solves your issue,here it is :

I found that xcode 9 is required some libraries in macOS high Sierra. That's my case.

So install it then it will work:

https://www.apple.com/lae/macos/high-sierra/

Comment: I have been using MacOS High Sierra. Let me know which lib is required ? I did not find any specific

Comment: If you have successfully updated to MacOS High Sierra, and still facing issue, try to remove the blue lines as suggested:,

In Xcode, Go to Editor > Canvas > Show Bounds Rectangles

This will hide the blue line

Comment: Well I am using the Mac OS high sierra. Actually on git If I use a particular commit of code then I face issue.

Comment: If it is so, then it seems like a bug, you can report the same to Apple.

Comment: Thanks. I will get back to you in case I found out the reason why it happened for particular commit. As I switched to another commit it worked well .

Comment: @Madhur Worked for me.. Thanks :)